What is the specific function of the beforeCommit in TransactionSynchronizationAdapter?
What is the difference between placing logic inside the beforeCommit method versus writing it directly within the transactional scope? Does using beforeCommit offer any specific advantages?
I have been reading about the TransactionSynchronizationAdapter, and most of the examples I found online focus on using afterCommit. However, I am curious about the exact role of the beforeCommit method.
I understand that placing code in the beforeCommit method of the TransactionSynchronizationAdapter can trigger a rollback if an exception occurs, similar to how logic within the transactional method would behave. So, why would one prefer to put logic in beforeCommit rather than writing it directly in the transactional method itself? What advantages or specific use cases justify placing the logic in beforeCommit just before the transaction commits?

It could for instance be used to check if what is about to be commited is valid.
Assume a service creates entities that are valid only before a given deadline (or some other criteria), but the service is called by multiple other services, that may do (long running) stuff after the service was called. Using beforeCommit, the service can check validity itself before the commit, without needing to know the calling code
